# How to open/save docx file to be aditted as xml and save the result as docx after editting using python

Tags: python, xml, docx

I have a `docx` file in which I need to edit its paragraphs (the paragraphs might contain equations). I tried to do these jobs using `python-docx` but it was not successful since editing the text of each paragraph and replacing it with the edited new paragraph needs to call `p.add_paragraphs(editText(paragraph.text))` which ignores and omits any mathematical equation.

By searching for a method to gain this goal I found that this job is possible through XML codes by finding `<w:t>` tags and editing their content like this:

```
tree= ET.parse(filename)
root=tree.getroot()

for par in root.findall('w:p'):
   if par.find('w:r'):
   myText= par.find('w:r').find('w:t')
   myText.text= editText(myText.text)
```

Then I must save the result as docx.
My quation is: what the format of filename is? should it be a document.xml file? If so, how can I reach that from my original document.docx file? and one more question is that how can I save the result as a .docx file again?

For saving docx as xml, I have given a try to save it by `document.save('Document2.xml'`). But the content of the result was not correct.

Would you give me some advice how to do them?

Comment: You need to look up a primer on the .docx format – even if it's only the source of python-docx.

Comment: _Then I must save the result as docx. My quation is: what the format of filename is?_ Assuming that you're asking what the format of the output file is, doesn't the previous sentence answer that question?

Comment: @AMC: Not really. As I understood from the link Harry Potter introduced bellow, and from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102743/how-can-i-copy-equations-from-docx-to-a-specific-location-in-another-docx), ET.parse needs an XML file which is found after reading the docx file as a zip file ( you check it via renaming .docx to .zip and checking its subfiles)

Comment: _but it was not successful since editing the text of each paragraph...._ Shouldn’t we be focusing on that, rather than on a particular attempt at a solution?

Comment: @AMC: You are right. I tried for it, and after struggling to do it (since my paragraphs contain equations- although I don't need to edit the equations they must not be omitted from the result). I asked for help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60225970/copying-a-paragraph-containing-inline-mathematical-formulas-using-python-docx) for just focusing on the goal, but I didn't received any help there.

Answer (score 1):

Not experienced with this at all, but perhaps this is what you were looking for?
https://virantha.com/2013/08/16/reading-and-writing-microsoft-word-docx-files-with-python/
From the article:

```py
import zipfile
from lxml import etree
class DocsWriter:
    def __init__(self, docx_file):
        self.zipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(docx_file)


    def _write_and_close_docx (self, xml_content, output_filename):
        """ Create a temp directory, expand the original docx zip.
            Write the modified xml to word/document.xml
            Zip it up as the new docx
        """

        tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

        self.zipfile.extractall(tmp_dir)

        with open(os.path.join(tmp_dir,'word/document.xml'), 'w') as f:
            xmlstr = etree.tostring (xml_content, pretty_print=True)
            f.write(xmlstr)

        # Get a list of all the files in the original docx zipfile
        filenames = self.zipfile.namelist()
        # Now, create the new zip file and add all the filex into the archive
        zip_copy_filename = output_filename
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_copy_filename, "w") as docx:
            for filename in filenames:
                docx.write(os.path.join(tmp_dir,filename), filename)

        # Clean up the temp dir
        shutil.rmtree(tmp_dir)
```

From what I can tell, this code block writes an `xml` document as `.docx`. Refer to the article for more context.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. Actually, I have tested the first part of it successfully to read a zip file. But for saving, I don't know what the type of the self (in _write_and_close_docx (self, xml_content, output_filename) is. What is its type? what I must pass to (/call by) it?

Comment: I have used this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102743/how-can-i-copy-equations-from-docx-to-a-specific-location-in-another-docx) also. Unfortunately, for saving it uses _UpdateableZipFile_ without mentioning its resource.

Comment: :it (self in above function)  is something that has 'zipfile' as an attribute!!!!

Comment: @m123 The name `self` is almost always used to refer to the object calling the method, you don’t need to pass anything yourself. Unfortunately, I’m not sure what the context for this function is.

Comment: @m123 Right. Sorry to have passed along an incomplete code segment, it appears that the author left out some important bits. Heres the explanation they gave later on: 
I haven't really shown the whole code here, so sorry if that was confusing. It's the `ZipFile` object, and that member variable gets set in my `__init__` as `self.zipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(docx_file)`

Comment: @m123 Updated the code snippet with the missing fragment, let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not the best tool for this.  Use VBA if you need to automate something in a Word document, or multiple Word documents.  I can't tell what you are even trying to do here, but let's start at the beginning, with something simple.  If, for instance, you want to loop through all paragraphs in your Word document, and select only the equations, you can run the code below to do just that.

```
Sub SelectAllEquations()
Dim xMath As OMath
Dim I As Integer
With ActiveDocument
    .DeleteAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone
    For I = 1 To .OMaths.Count
        Set xMath = .OMaths.Item(I)
        xMath.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone
    Next
    .SelectAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone
    .DeleteAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone
End With
End Sub
```

Again, I don't know what your end game is, but I think it's worthwhile to start with something like that, and build on your foundation.

Comment: Thank you but I prefer a solution by python (if possible) since I have written my program using python-docx and I'm not familiar with VBA.

After some works, my program omits the spaces between some special words (for this latter I use a prepared library, I just call its functions). As I explained above, I tested .'add_paragraphs(editText(paragraph.text))'. But .text reads only plain text parts of .docx file and ignores equations.

While searching, I found a way to do that via editing XML which is explained above. But I am not able to reach XML from docx and vice versa